# WPF: Error getting UserControl into ToolBox

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, toolbox

I can remember that some time ago when I created a UserControl in Visual Studio 2008 the USerControls automatically appeared in the ToolBox.

Now they don't. If use "Choose Items.." on the ToolBox I get the error message "The given assembly name or codebase was invalid", after selecting my assembly.

I have Windows XP SP3 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. It only happens when using the WPF designer toolbox, on WinForms everything works as it should.

I'm using Windows 7, VS2008, .Net 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems VS2008 simply doesn't support this.